# Is there any reason to have the Legacy Event adapter installed if you don't have a legacy events system?

Tags: event-system

On more than one occasion, I have come across Tridion systems that have the Legacy Event adapter installed/configured, even though they have no legacy events system. I'm fairly convinced that this is not only unnecessary, but actually a bad idea.

Are there any circumstances where removing it would have unintended or unexpected consequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you don't have legacy event handlers, by all means get rid of that legacy event adapter.